# C++ string does not concatenate in a class

Tags: c++, string, class, raspberry-pi, concatenation

i try to write a small program to control a pump and a valve connected with two ds18b20 temperature sensors on a raspberry pi 3B+. I defined a class for the pump and one for the valve, in the future more pumps and valves will be added, i also created a class for the ds18b20 sensor that is connected over 1 wire. The sensor can read out via a "file", so there is a base directory `string baseDir = "/sys/bus/w1/devices/";` followed by the device id `string tSensor1 = "28-3c01a81688f4";` and the temperature "file" `string tempFile = "/w1_slave";`, the full path should look like this `/sys/bus/w1/devices/28-3c01a81688f4/w1_slave`.

BUT what i get is this `TestSensor1= Error reading file at /sys/bus/w1/devices//w1_slave` the device is missing, the same for `TestSensor2= Error reading file at /sys/bus/w1/devices//w1_slave`.

the code is directly compiled on the rPi with `g++ -Wall -o oww ofen-warmwasser.cpp -lwiringPi`
this is my code

```
#include <wiringPi.h> // library to access the GPIO Pins on a raspberryPI !!deprecated!!
#include <iostream>   // cout
#include <fstream>    // file stream access
#include <string>     // string class
#include <sstream>    // string stream needed for file access to put data into string

//... code skipped ...

class temperaturSensor {
  private:
    string device;
    string baseDir = "/sys/bus/w1/devices/";
    string tempFile = "/w1_slave";
    string path = baseDir + device + tempFile;
    stringstream buffer;
    string data;
    string strTemp;
    double temp = 987.6;
  public:
    // constructor declaration
    temperaturSensor(string str);
    // methodes
    double temperatur() {
      //cout << "----->>>> " << device << " ----->>>> " << path << endl;
      ifstream infile(path);
      if (infile) {
        buffer << infile.rdbuf();
        data = buffer.str();
        infile.close();
      }
      else {
        infile.close();
        cout << "Error reading file at " << path << endl;
        return -100;
      }
      size_t crcCheck = data.find("YES");
      if (crcCheck == string::npos) {
        cout << "CRC fail not reading temperatur" << endl;
        return -101;
      }
      size_t TempPos = data.find("t=");
      if (TempPos == string::npos) {
        cout << "failed to find value -> abort!" << endl;
        return -102;
      }
      strTemp = data.substr(TempPos+2);
      temp = stod(strTemp)/1000;
      return temp;
    }
};

// constructor
    temperaturSensor::temperaturSensor(string str) {
       device = str;
    }

int main(void) {
  // test setup
  pump boilerpumpe(21);
  valve boilervalve(28);
  string tSensor1 = "28-3c01a81688f4";
  temperaturSensor testSensor1(tSensor1);
  temperaturSensor testSensor2("28-3c01a816d9c1");
  while (true)
  {
    boilerpumpe.on();
    boilervalve.close();
    cout << "TestSensor1= " << testSensor1.temperatur() << "°C \nTestSensor2= " << testSensor2.temperatur() << "°C" << endl;
    delay(5*1000);
    boilerpumpe.off();
    boilervalve.open();
    delay(5*1000);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

as you might see in the code i tried different things from declaring the the `string device;` variable from private: to public: from the end of the class to the beginning, when i `cout` the device variable it gets correctly displayed, i think the problem is somewhere here `string path = baseDir + device + tempFile;`, i also tried `string path = baseDir.append(device);` but with no success

any help appreciated, if more information is needed just tell me what and i try to provide

thanks etch

Comment: You're initializing the value of `path` before you've set a value for `device`. Don't try to set a value for `path` until you know what it actually is, i.e. in the constructor.

Comment: @NathanPierson thank you makes totally sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your class declaration:

```
string device;
```

This class member is default-initialized to an empty string.

```
string baseDir = "/sys/bus/w1/devices/";
```

This class member gets default-initialized to the given string.

```
string tempFile = "/w1_slave";
```

This class member gets default-initialized to the given string.

```
string path = baseDir + device + tempFile;
```

And this class member gets initialized to the combined string. Remember that `device` is an empty string, so path ends up getting set to "/sys/bus/w1/devices//w1_slave", which is what your code ends up attempting to open, and fails.

In your class's constructor:

```
   device = str;
```

This sets a new value for `device`. However it is too late, since the other class member, and `path` specifically, are already initialized. It's not going to get initialized again, after the value of `device` gets set. C++ does not work this way.

The simplest fix here is for your constructor to use its initialization section to initialize all class members, in order.

Answer (score 0):

You have default member initialisers for three of your member variables. These will be executed before the assignment of `device` in the body of your constructor, at which time device will still be an empty string.

```
class temperaturSensor {
  private:
    string device;
    string baseDir = "/sys/bus/w1/devices/";
    string tempFile = "/w1_slave";
    string path = baseDir + device + tempFile;
```

It seems that the values for `baseDir` and `tempFile` don't ever change and so it would probably be simplest to make them const static, and then initialise `path` after initialising `device` in your constructor, or using the value of the argument passed into it.